# Getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: sfdcPage is not defined" when loading Visualforce page in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, jquery

I have a Visualforce page that launches from a custom button, and this VF page launches fine into a new window in Classic. However, this button does not render properly in Lightning. The page "loads" visually but does not scroll or resize properly. This is a legacy page has over +5000 lines of JQuery code in a  tag, and this page will be deprecated in the near future, so we are looking for a band-aid fix rather than rebuilding using LWC.

Below are things we have tried, but in all the scenarios in Lightning, I noticed that "Uncaught ReferenceError: sfdcPage is not defined" prints to Console.

Things we have tried:

- Hard coding in a scroll bar to the VF page
- Tried wrapping the VF page into a Lightning Component, using  within component, and launch this from Quick Action button

Comment: Are you able to create a new Community page that only contains that VF page, and then navigate to that Community page URL from the Action?

Comment: We tried that, but there were security issues that sensitive data could be exposed, so we steered away. The VF page is basically a different UI for editing a custom object with sensitive data.